# AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent - how do you distinguish between a bad password or bad username?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, frameworks

I am using AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent with the Spring Framework. In the code below, how do you get

```
AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent
```

to distinguish between whether a bad userid or bad password was entered by the user? Also, it appears that the typical way recommended to go to the jsp error web page (i.e. "Error: Invalid Credentials") is to have a url hardcoded in the spring security .xml file.  Does Spring provide a way to branch to a java program (some kind of controller? Or, another type of program?) and then pick a web page based on whether the user entered a userid or password?  (i.e. so I can do things like lock a user if they enter the wrong password 5 times in a row).

```
package test
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AbstractAuthenticationEvent;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserAuthenticationErrorHandler implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {

        Object userName = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Object credentials = event.getAuthentication().getCredentials();
        System.out.println("Failed login using USERNAME " + userName);
        System.out.println("Failed login using PASSWORD " + credentials);
    }
}
```

one reference:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html

Thanks for any advice on the above.

Comment: For reporting back to the user you don't want to do that, if you expose the actual reason you give hackers a change to obtain usernames. For the recording simply keep a counter in the database (reset after successful login). If there is no user no need to keep the counter...

Comment: Here is a related scenario:  The user keeps entering the incorrect userid. (i.e. 10 times with minor variations of spelling - maybe they are trying to hack into the system). Since the user is not in the database, how can the userid/password be authenticated?  Although I don't want to display an error message on the web page that tells the user that they entered an incorrect password, I need to know whether the password is incorrect versus the userid. I can do a database call from UserAuthenticationErrorHandler, but this would be repeating what has already been done.

Comment: And why would that be a problem, it is a different usecase... Create the logic as you would and don't try to depend on the upstream system/logic.

Comment: M. Deinum - I think I see what you are saying. If the user is not in the database, a counter is not incremented for this particular user trying to logon.

Answer (score 1):

From working with the code above, I came up with a few improvements:

1. It might be more appropriate to use AuthenticationFailureHandler, since it uses HttpServletRequest request where as 
   AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent doesn't appear to give you access to HttpServletRequest request.

org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler

Strategy used to handle a failed authentication attempt. 
Typical behaviour might be to redirect the user to the authentication page (in the case of a form 
 login) to allow them to try again. More sophisticated logic might be implemented depending on 
 the type of the exception. For example, a CredentialsExpiredException might cause a redirect to 
 a web controller which allowed the user to change their password.
Since:
     3.0

2. It can be useful to pull the username out of the exception: exception.getExtraInformation().toString().

Answer (score 0):

A couple years late but anyway, if anyone reading this absolutely needs to get the HttpServletRequest and also wants to stick with AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent you can get the actual request using the ServletRequestAttributes:

```
private static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attrs = 
       (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    if (attrs == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return attrs.getRequest();
}
```